# How do I create a web chat between only 2 users using strictly javascript/jquery/ajax(No node.js/socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am in a front end internship interview where I was told to build a web chat for just two users and focus on the functionality not the ui.

This question shocked me and I'm not sure where to begin as I'm of the opinion that chat apps used only server side scripting

Help!!! I am a newbie developer, how is my js code supposed to look like?

Comment: Use ajax to write the response to a database and use polling to retrieve the latest messages from the database.

Comment: A friend of mine had the exact same question in his job interview and used ajax calls every with a timeout of 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misinterpret the constraints? The way i see it you need some form of webserver to facilitate pageloads and storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without server side scripting.

You need:

1. SQL database to store chat
2. PHP to pull data from database and send it
3. Ajax to refresh displayed content

Comment: Only way to make it without server would be like splitting page in 2 parts and working with JS to store data until page is refreshed

Comment: Depends on requirement you may not need a database. Btw. there are more options then just PHP.

Comment: @Werner PHP was just an example. What do you mean by "Depends on requirement"? If there's no server then there's no online chat

Comment: Yes, You need a server but you don't _need_ a database. Eg.: You could store the commited text in ram/session as long as the other user didn't requested it. You could also store the texts in a simple text file (I know, this is a bit odd)